# Multiple Content Shortcodes

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

I was trying to create a shortcode for a multiple tabs panel. The user can set the number of tabs, the titles and the content for each. It would be something like :

```
[tabs number='4']

[tab title='First_tab_title']first tab content[/first_tab]
...
...

[/tabs]
```

Now, i am wondering. Although it can be done like this, i don't like that i have to create separate shortcodes, like tabs and tab. Is there another better way to pass all this information to a single [tabs] shortcode ?

Comment: I wouldn't use shortcodes like this. Why don't you make a TinyMCE plugin instead?

Comment: i have a tinymce plugin, i'm not gonna do it by hand. But the output of the shortcode must be like this. It has to be a shortcode in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to hack a conditional for 1 shortcode but it seems wonky. Typically you use 2 parameters just like you were using raw html.

There is a smart way around this using custom fields ( which I just happened to do recently).

It does not use any shortcodes at all, the logic is simple it has a custom fields called "tab 1, tab 2, tab 3 , etc" , if no data is entered no tab panels shows up, if there is data in the tab field the panels shows up and dynamically adds tabs per field that is filled out.

I just use jquery tools for the tab panel and default WordPress conditionals for the meta fields, `get_post_custom_values` specifically.